# jquery selectable not working on a dynamically loaded table

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamically-generated, selectable

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to make table rows selectable on a dynamically loaded (AJAX call) content, but it's not working. It *is* working in a standard HTML page; the following works:

```
<style>
    #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
    #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
    #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#selectable").selectable({
            filter: 'tr',
            selected: function(event, ui) {
                alert("row selected");
            }
        });
     });
</script>

<table id="selectable" border="1px">
    <tr><td>val1</td><td>Val2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Val3</td><td>Val4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Val5</td><td>Val5</td></tr>
</table>
```

But if I load this data in a `div` using `$("my-div").html(same-data-from-ajax).trigger('create')`, then it does not work.

This is what I have:

- Main html with one button
- js with:

  ```
  $("#button").click(function {
      $.ajax({
          url: "./php/testselect.php", // this returns above html code
              cache: false,
              success: onSuccessSelect,
              error: onError
          });
  });
  function onSuccessSelect(data, status) {
      $("#my-div").html(data).trigger('create');
  }
  ```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest solution in your case would be to re-apply `selectable` to the newly created elements:

```
function onSuccessSelect(data, status) {
    $("#my-div").html(data).trigger('create');
    $("#my-div").find("#selectable").selectable({
        filter: 'tr',
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            alert("row selected");
        }
    });
}
```

I'd also suggest, if you have more than one table you might want to make selectable, to use a class instead of an id (ex.: `<table class="selectable">` and `find(".selectable")`).

Comment: @user1917138 I've set up a working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KpDXc/), check it and see if you can make your page work. Otherwise, tell me what's wrong and I'll see if I can help. BTW I think there's a typo in your `$("#button").click(function {` (missing `()` after `function`).

Comment: I think I know what the problem is now..it does not work when I use JQM, It works in JQ but not with JQM

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions worked for me. It seems that selectable can be applied onpageload javascript execution. The fiddle provided by mgibsonbr did not work for me. what i did is a hack and it is a dirty one.

after adding the element i simply reload the page from cache without touching the server.

location.reload();